# C11: Typedef of an anonymous struct works with pointers to the typedef as a member?

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, incomplete-type

Here is how I would usually define a Node for a linked list in C:

```
typedef struct _Node {
    int value;
    struct _Node * next;
} Node;
```

With some testing, I have found that I am able to get this definition to work via an anonymous struct, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;
```

Is there a reason why this works? I feel like it shouldn't work since Node isn't a type yet in the struct definition.

My hypothesis is that the struct Node * next is an anonymous struct itself that only has a pointer to a Node. But if this is the case then how am I able to use the Node type here if the typedef isn't resolved yet?

Answer (score 3):

This only seems to work. The "tag" name space and the name space of "ordinary identifiers" are completely distinct in C. (C++ has slightly different rules)

Your member `next` of the anonymous `struct` points to an incomplete `struct Node` that is forward-declared by that same declaration.

Your `typedef` names an anonymous `struct` that is distinct from that type `struct Node`. So your pointer `next` points to a type for which the compiler knows nothing more than that it is a `struct`.

A good strategy to avoid such headaches is to forward declare `struct Node` and the `typedef` to be the same:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
               ^^^^ ^^^^
               tag  typedef name
```

and then

```
struct Node {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;
```

introduces two structure specifiers. The first one is the unnamed structure with the typedef name `Node`. The second one is the named structure `struct Node`.

These two structure specifiers are different.

So for example the compiler will issue a warning or an error when you will try to assign a pointer of the type `Node *` to a pointer of the type `struct Node *` or vice versa because there are used incompatible pointer types.

Consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
} Node;

int main( void )
{
    Node *head = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    head->value = 1;
    head->next = NULL;

    Node *next = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    next->value = 2;
    next->next = NULL;

    head->next = next;
}
```

For the statement

```
head->next = next;
```

for example the compiler gcc 11.2 issues the following warnings

```
<source>:18:16: warning: assignment to 'struct Node *' from incompatible pointer type 'Node *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   18 |     head->next = next;
      |                ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:18:16: warning: assignment to 'struct Node *' from incompatible pointer type 'Node *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   18 |     head->next = next;
      |
```

Moreover you will be unable to dereference a pointer of the type `struct Node *` because the type `struct Node` is an incomplete type. The definition of `struct Node` is unknown.

For example if you will append the above demonstration program with statement

```
printf( "%d\n", head->next->value );
```

then the compiler at this time will issue the following error message

```
<source>:21:31: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct Node'
   21 |     printf( "%d\n", head->next->value );
      |                               ^~
```

Instead you could write for example

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node * next;
};
```